# How to fix files with gulp-eslint?

Tags: node.js, gulp, eslint

I'm using gulp with [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-eslint).

Without gulp, I just run `eslint ./src --fix`. I can't figure out how to make this happen with gulp. I tried below, setting fix to be true, but it doesn't fix any files:

```
gulp.task('lint', ['./src/**.js'], () => {
return gulp.src()
    .pipe($.eslint({fix:true}))
    .pipe($.eslint.format())
    .pipe($.eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

I want all the files under `./src` to be fixed. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the right way that is working in my project:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if');


function isFixed(file) {
    // Has ESLint fixed the file contents?
    return file.eslint != null && file.eslint.fixed;
}


gulp.task('lint', function () {
    // ESLint ignores files with "node_modules" paths.
    // So, it's best to have gulp ignore the directory as well.
    // Also, Be sure to return the stream from the task;
    // Otherwise, the task may end before the stream has finished.
    return gulp.src(['./src/**.js','!node_modules/**'])
        // eslint() attaches the lint output to the "eslint" property
        // of the file object so it can be used by other modules.
        .pipe(eslint({fix:true}))
        // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console.
        // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs).
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        // if fixed, write the file to dest
        .pipe(gulpIf(isFixed, gulp.dest('../test/fixtures')))
        // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on
        // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failAfterError 
        // last.
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('default', ['lint'], function () {
    // This will only run if the lint task is successful...
});
```

Comment: _WHY_ is this the "right way"? Particularly, why should "FailAfterError()" be removed?

Comment: You are using the "gulp-if" package, correct? It's not referenced in your example. With that in mind, and with the naming style used in the packages example, I have the following working code for output: `.pipe(gulpif(isFixed, gulp.dest('./')));`

Answer (score 2):

Old question but adding `.pipe(gulp.dest(file => file.base))` is what got it to work for me. As in:

```
gulp.task('lint', ['./src/**.js'], () => {
return gulp.src()
    .pipe($.eslint({fix:true}))
    .pipe($.eslint.format())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(file => file.base)) // <-- NEW: Output fixed version of file.
    .pipe($.eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [gulp-eslint-new](https://github.com/fasttime/gulp-eslint-new) because gulp-eslint is unmaintained.

It has a method `gulpESLintNew.fix()` to fix files, which is explained in the readme.

> Overwrite files with the fixed content provided by ESLint. This should be used in conjunction with the option `fix` in `gulpESLintNew(options)`. Files without a fix and files that were not processed by ESLint will be left untouched.

And an [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fasttime/gulp-eslint-new/db0ce2803cdd422112759af7607d6adb6820c9c8/example/fix.js):

```js
function lintNFix() {
  return src('demo/**/*.js').pipe(gulpESLintNew({ fix: true }))
                            .pipe(gulpESLintNew.format())
                            // If a file has a fix, overwrite it.
                            .pipe(gulpESLintNew.fix());
}
```